# Sqoop Big Data : How to import an address field with a comma using sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a csv data like:

```
id,name,address,city,state
111,'Mona','E103,abc society','Pune','Maharashtra'
```

How to import this file data to hive using sqoop?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be with sqoop?

You can do this using hive directly.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bdp.hv_csv_table
(id STRING,Code STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/user/root/bdp/ld_csv_hv/ip';
```

Comment: Do you know what the csv file means? It is 
literally Comma-separated values.
The question has been edited I think

Comment: Original post did not have commas https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/087e181d-1221-4ab7-a8c9-293d2cd321d0/view-source

Comment: You're right @OneCricketeer. Do you think the answer now applies?

Comment: Using the correct field names and skipping the header of the file, then sure